# Excel 2010 - Find and Add

Tags: excel, sum, find, match, vlookup

[Current Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFTE7.jpg)

I need to find all instances of each value in "Column B" - Product Number and then add each value from "Column C" - QTY to get a total amount of the product number.

I want the answer to the function to be placed in "Column I" on the same row as the value of "Column B".

Here is what I would like the result to look like.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQVpT.jpg)

*Note* Please ignore all information in Columns G and H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type this formula in cell `I85` then copy/paste in all the column:

```
=SUMIF(B:B, B85, C:C)
```

If you want the cells of column I to stay blank when the corresponding cell in column B is blank, use

```
=IF(LEN(TRIM(B85))=0, "", SUMIF(B:B, B85, C:C))
```

Comment: That formula almost works. The problem is it returns the sum of all the cells that contain the value in column b. I need it to be an exact match.

Comment: `SUMIF` performs an exact match, unless you put an wildcard `*` in the criteria (`B85`), which doesn't seem to be the case in your figures

Comment: Do you mean that you want the cell of column I to stay blank if the corresponding cell in column B is blank? Is that the issue?

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked exactly as I wanted. And showing me that 2nd formula, it makes it look so much nicer. Again thank you.